# PHP & Virtuemart: change color of a number if this number is bigger than 1

Tags: php, virtuemart

The code at the virtumart is:

```
<th align="center" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;"><?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_PRINT_QTY') ?></th>
```

What I need is the following:
When the `COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_PRINT_QTY` is bigger than 1, the font color to be somehtinge else, `for example red` (the format I will do it later, now I just want the "if" code).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
<?php
    $quantity = JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_PRINT_QTY');
    if($quantity > 1){
        echo '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCC; color:#FF0000">'.$quantity.'</th>';
    }else{
        echo '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">'.$quantity.'</th>';
    }
?>
```